# DFA which recognises the language {ϵ,a,b}

Tags: automation, dfa

How could I show that there exist infinitely many DFA's each of which recognises the language {ϵ,a,b}.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you are counting DFAs. Clearly there is one DFA for the language, and you can always add an unreachable state to the automaton. Ordinarily, though, such trivial differences are discounted, and with a finite language, there are only a finite number of different DFAs. With an infinite language there would be cycles in the transition graph which can be expanded again and again, which makes for a more significant difference. Another way to put it, you cannot show that there exist an infinite number of different DFAs for the given finite language.